# Show $\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 {f(x)x\sin(ax^2)}=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

> Suppose $f$ is integrable on $(0,1)$, then show $$\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 {f(x)x\sin(ax^2)}=0.$$

I tried to write $$(0,1) = \bigcup _{k=0}^{{a-1}} \left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{a}},\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{a}}\right),$$ but cannot make the integral converge to $0$.

Comment: Substitute $x^2 \to x$.  Then, $$\int_0^1 xf(x)\sin(ax^2)\,dx=\frac12 \int_0^1 f(\sqrt x)\sin(ax)\,dx$$Then, apply the [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma#Statement).

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, I can use the Laplace transformation to get the result, but it is only allowed to use the basic ttechnology.

Comment: What do you mean "basic technology?"  Substitution and the RLL are standard/basic tools.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks I will try to do some exercise about these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:

Split $[0, 1]$
into the intervals where
$ax^2 = 2\pi n$,
$ax^2 = \pi(2 n+1)$,
$ax^2 = \pi(2 n+2)$.
These are
$I_{2n}
=[\sqrt{\frac{2\pi n}{a}}, \sqrt{\frac{\pi(2 n+1)}{a}})
$
and
$I_{2n+1}
=[\sqrt{\frac{\pi(2 n+1)}{a}}, \sqrt{\frac{\pi(2 n+2)}{a}})
$.

Since
$\sin(ax^2) > 0$
in
$I_{2n}$
and
$\sin(ax^2) < 0$
in
$I_{2n+1}$,
show that
the integral over
$I_{2n} \cup I_{2n+1}$
goes to zero.

Comment: Give me one sec, I will try this.